# How to change sound frequency on Android device using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, equalizer

i have a problem, i want to change phone sound frequency like this library: https://github.com/bullheadandplato/AndroidEqualizer

i use audiomanager to be able to control the audio player but i don't know how to get the sessionId of the current audio. Everyone help me

I tried with this code

```
if (getArguments() != null && getArguments().containsKey(ARG_AUDIO_SESSIOIN_ID)) {
    audioSessionId = getArguments().getInt(ARG_AUDIO_SESSIOIN_ID);
    Log.e("duylt", "Check SessionId: " + audioSessionId);
}
```

but the returned results are all 1

Comment: You should improve the title of your question: It should read "How to find the sessionId of the current audio". And by the way: An equalizer does not change the **frequencies** of a sound, but the **loudness** of the individual tones.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val audioManager: AudioManager = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
val sessionId = audioManager.generateAudioSessionId()
```